# How to delete lines between two search-matches using ed line editor

Tags: xml, text, ed

I have a text file I am editing (in my case a JMeter XML) and I use ed to find two lines that mark the 1st and last lines of a XML section.

How can I delete the lines between the two search matches?

example file:

```
1 <hashTree>
2 <ConstantTimer guiclass="ConstantTimerGui" testclass="ConstantTimer" testname="Constant Timer" enabled="true">
3 <stringProp name="ConstantTimer.delay">300</stringProp>
4 </ConstantTimer>
6 </hashTree>
```

and I want to delete lines 2-4 included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do all of them, you can use the `g` command to find the start, then use the `+` to start at the next line, then search forward to the closing tag, and use `-` to move backward, then delete the resulting content:

```
g/<hashTree>/+,/<\/hashTree>/-d
```

Beware that this assumes every `<hashTree>` block has **some** content to delete.  If there are any empty blocks, it may end up deleting more content than you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can mark the lines you find and perform a delete between the two marks using the following code

```
1                    <---- Jump to line 1
/ConstantTimer       <---- Search for the first 'ConstantTimer'
kx                   <---- Mark it as 'x'
/ConstantTimer       <---- Search for the second 'ConstantTimer'
ky                   <---- Mark it as 'y'
'x,'yd               <---- delete between the two marks 'x and 'y
w                    <---- save the changes
q                    <---- quit ed
```